# How to create a TabView with icon and title like the image i attached below using NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you have the img/icon/glyph for each tab?

Comment: if you do, what are they? img/icon/glyph?

Comment: try this this can customize to your requirement  https://dzone.com/articles/learning-angular-2-creating-a-tabs-component

Comment: janith1024, that doesnt answer his question as it doesnt include images/icons/glyphs

Comment: I don't have the img/icon/glyph.  @mast3rd3mon I tried the example in creating TabView from the NativeScript documentation but it only display the Tab title. It does not display any icon.  Can you show me the solution for this?

Comment: i can but you're gonna need the img/icon/glyph within your project for this to work

Comment: @janith1024  Sorry, I did not specify what platform I'm gonna make. I wanted to create IOS and Android app with NativeScript but I don't know how to display the tab-icon. I looked on the site you attached but it's for web not for mobile.

Comment: I can give an example but without any img/icon/glyph in your project, it probably wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a TabView with icon in NativeScript, you should setup TabViewItem `iconSource` property. You should set the image path or the image name if you load them from the Resources. The important part for iOS is to setup `iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal"` property, which will allow showing properly the image in the tab

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">

    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <GridLayout>
        <TabView id="tabViewContainer" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal">
            <TabView.items>
                <TabViewItem title="Tab 1" iconSource="res://icon">
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 1" />
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>
                <TabViewItem title="Tab 2" iconSource="res://icon">
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2" />
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>
            </TabView.items>
        </TabView>

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is based on glyphs from Ionicons but can be easily adapted.

```
<TabViewItem title="title">
   <TabViewItem.view>
       <FormattedString>
           <Span fontSize="40" fontFamily="ionicons" text="&#xf456;"></Span> <!--Image/Logo-->
           <Span fontSize="10" text="&#xA;"></Span> <!--BreakLine-->
           <Span fontSize="10" text="Text"></Span> <!--Text-->
       </FormattedString>
   </TabViewItem.view>
 </TabViewItem>
```

Comment: its ok, it can be changed for images/icons as well